# Mosh via two-level ssh (FreeBSD, jails)

Tags: ssh, freebsd, jail

I am fond of [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) but I have problem connecting via two-level ssh. Consider this scenario:

- host machine running FreeBSD which has closed all ports from outside
- first jail having ssh port 2222 open from the outside is on public IP let's say door.example.com
- second jail with private IP address named DEV.example.com that can be ssh-ed from door.example.com on port 2222 as well
- redirection is set up to forward udp port 60000 from door.example.com to DEV.example.com

There is generaly some problem with ttys and jails, but I am able to connect this way:

```
ssh -t -t -p2222 door.example.com -- ssh -p2222 DEV.example.com
```

being asked for both password to door.example.com and DEV.example.com afterwards.

I have tried this mosh command (also tried all variations with and without `-t -t` params):

```
mosh --port 60000 \
  --ssh "ssh -t -t -p2222" \
  --server "ssh -t -t -p2222 DEV.example.com mosh-server" \
  door.example.com
```

but I always get hanging on password authentication to the second jail with no password prompt.

Funny thing is that from [android mosh-flavored irssi connect bot](http://dan.drown.org/android/mosh/) this works when I set up mosh port to 60000 and as mosh server I fill in `ssh -t -t -p2222 DEV.example.com mosh-server`

I know there are ways to set-up ssh proxy but I don't want to have things like netcat on the door jail. This should work somehow especially because it already works from my phone.

Comment: Ah, it seems that on linux only the password prompt is not displayed - I entered the second password and the request goes successfully through. But on Mac OS X I cannot go through - so problem is probably on Mac OS X ssh...

Comment: On Mac OS X I updated the openssh from homebrew and still the request can't go through the second ssh. So I'm still stuck.

Comment: Have you tried the verbose options of ssh ?

Comment: of course I did - both in `--ssh` and `--server` and combinations. It hangs on the authentication.

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/q/390916/80866

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason the `mosh-server` needs to be at the end point (dev) rather than at the entry (door)?

I use something like:

```
mosh --port 60000 \
     --ssh "ssh -t -t -p2222" \
     -- door.example.com ssh -t -t -p2222 dev.example.com
```

For my setup at home.

FWIW, I use something like this for irssi:

```
mosh --ssh="ssh -p2222" \
     -- user@dmz.example.com ssh -q -t user@irssi.example.com \
                 screen -c /home/user/.screen.irc -UxaA irc
```

Both my servers are FreeBSD and clients are either MacBook Air or a laptop running Ubuntu.  I had gone with a dmz host with host based firewall, to overcome the limited forwards available on my current router.

Comment: I don't want to install any software in the entry jail so that is not a solution for me.